# Returning a counter value from a method and storing it in main method

Tags: java

I need to return a counter from a method to main in order to count up total amount of actions that the counter has.  This method is being called a number of times so it is throwing out the counts from the original trial before it.

```
public static int method()
{

    int counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
         System.out.println("hello");
         counter++
   }
    return counter;
}
```

Call:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    findNum();
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: probably its going into infinite loop because `while(!found)` is never false.

Comment: How do you know the method works?

Comment: show how you're calling the method

Comment: @rafi Kamal, you shouldn't have fixed syntax in your edit...although that could've contributed to the issue lol

Comment: @Khal_Drogo33 If that's how you're calling `findNum()`, you're not even saving the result anywhere!

Comment: You need to store the return value, something like  `count = findNum()`

Comment: Edit the question and update code, instead of writing it in comments @Khal_Drogo33

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the average, you would want to sum the return value of `findNum()`:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    hideNum();
    sum += findNum();
    clearTable();
}
```

Now you can find average using the `sum` value.